# java 8 Hibernate org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

I have referred to SO questions related to org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity but none of them answer my issue.

I have an entity with the following 2 attributes (among others):

```
@Column(name="rollno", nullable=false, updatable=false)
protected String rollno;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) // 1:1 must be n:1 in order for @JoinFormula to work!
@JoinFormula(value="crypto.decrypt(rollno)", referencedColumnName="rollno")
@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
protected Student student;
```

This works in java 6. The same code and hibernate libraries on java 8 fail during construction of the sessionFactory with the following error:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.bean.entity.Insuredperson:org.hibernate.MappingException:Unknown entity: com.bean.entity.Insuredperson
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:810)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getIdentifierType(SessionFactoryImpl.java:939)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifierType(EntityType.java:553)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifierOrUniqueKeyType(EntityType.java:593)
        at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.requireIdentifierOrUniqueKeyType(ManyToOneType.java:112)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Dec 11, 2018 2:42:25,696 PM CET> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Administration Console encountered the following error: weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.bean.entity.Student.hibernate.MappingException:Unknown entity: com.bean.entity.Student
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:810)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getIdentifierType(SessionFactoryImpl.java:939)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifierType(EntityType.java:553)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifierOrUniqueKeyType(EntityType.java:593)
        at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.requireIdentifierOrUniqueKeyType(ManyToOneType.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.getColumnSpan(ManyToOneType.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.create(EntityMetamodel.java:444)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.buildGenerationStrategyPair(EntityMetamodel.java:410)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:518)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor1041.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:356)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:423)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:711)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:727)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
```

It states the entity Student does not exist. However, if I remove the @Generated annotation from the student attribute, the sessionFactory is constructed without problems on java 8.

Hibernate version : 5.1.15.

Comment: Where do you register your entity with the persistence context?

Comment: I don't know how the classloading situation in Spring is, but classes not getting detected is solvable by listing them all in the `persistence.xml`. Normally this is only necessary if the `persistence.xml` and the scanned classes are not in the same jar/directory root tree.

Answer (score 1):

> Hibernate 5.2 and later versions require at least Java 1.8 and JDBC 4.2.Hibernate 5.1 and older versions require at least Java 1.6 and JDBC 4.0.

coming from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html)

try to upgrade your hibernate to 5.2 after using Java 1.8?

Comment: Not necessarily. Hibernate 5.1 supports java 8. Hibernate 5.1 require at least Java 1.6.

Comment: Can you try to see if it resolve your problem?  As there is no other change except java version in your description.

Comment: Even if its resolves the problem, there is no reason why it should be done unless this a bug.